# Astro/Vite: How to dynamically import CSS from an NPM package

Tags: vite, astrojs

I would like to dynamically import CSS from an NPM package in an Astro layout:

```
---
const { variant } = Astro.props;
import(`@pkg/lib/css/${variant}.css`);
---
```

But this gives me an error:

> Unknown file extension ".css"

Is there a way to achieve this?